# How to add libs to Classpath in my manifest file via maven?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

I using Maven 3 + hudson + artifacotory

I used the following

`<artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>  <addClasspath>true</addClasspath> <classpathPrefix>WEB-INF/lib/</classpathPrefix> </manifest>`

and I got the result as.....

```
WEB-INF/lib/gwt-servlet-2.4.0.jar WEB-INF/lib/gwt-user-2.4
 .0.jar WEB-INF/lib/validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar WEB-INF/lib/validation
 -api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar WEB-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar WEB-INF/lib/co
 mmons-lang-2.6.jar
```

I am find well and good.

My one more requirement is,

I need to add/append two more libs with the above manifest file. see below

```
/u01/app/TimesTen/tt1121/lib/orai18n.jar /u01/app/TimesTen/tt1121/lib/ttjdbc5.jar
```

So how can add/append this is to my Manifest, so that above 3 will be included?

Answer (score 1):

[maven war plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/war-manifest-guide.html) as well as maven jar plugin use [maven archiver](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/index.html) which in turn allows you [to specify your own manifest file](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/manifestFile.html). According to the documentation,

> The content of your own manifest file will be merged with the entries
>   generated by Maven Archiver.

Cut/pasting the relevant pom snippet from the above link for ready reference

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        ...
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifestFile>src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
        ...
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

So you could add the additional entries in this custom `MANIFEST.MF` and use it in conjunction with the maven war plugin.